# Sorting stacked bar graphs according to specific levels cumulative value?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given any normalised stacked bar graph using an X level factor as fill, is there any easy way to decide until which level cumulative value to sort?

I've tried searching the web for hours already and I only ever find answers on how to order/reorder levels within a factor, which I now definitely know how to do.

I seem to not be able to wrap my head around the operations required to sort multiple stacked graphs according to the cumulative values of e.g. all but the last level values.

x: Discrete values, each represented by a single bar e.g. A, B, C, D
y: Continuous values
f: factor, e.g. levels in years (2012:2018)

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(f=factor(sample(2012:2018, 500, replace=T)),
                 x=factor(sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 500, replace=T)),
                 y=sample(20:10000, 500, replace=T))

ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(x, y, fill = f),
                 position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE), stat = "identity") +
             scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```

Depending on the values y, the stacks are all over the place. It is easy to sort by y in general ascending/descending, however, is there a way to sort by only accumulating y values of e.g. 2 levels instead of all 4? Or e.g. sum up all values of levels 2012 until 2017 and sort accordingly?

Please let me know if anything is missing as this is my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the ordering of the stacked barcharts with respect to the cumulative values as fractions of the total value in 2018. Correct?

Then you have to tell the factor `x` how its levels have to be ordered. `ggplot` will then apply this order automatically. As you can see in the plot below, the stacked bars are ordered by the ascending values of the second stack (year 2013).

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(f=factor(sample(2012:2018, 500, replac e = T)),
                 x=factor(sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 500, replace = T)),
                 y=sample(20:10000, 500, replace = T))

# GET THE DESIRED ORDER
df %>%
  group_by(x, f) %>%
  summarise(Sum = sum(y)) %>%  # sum over years per group
  arrange(f) %>%  # sort by year
  transmute(f, frac = cumsum(Sum) / sum(Sum)) %>%  # get fractions of total value in 2018
  filter(f == 2013) %>%  # get the fractions for the second year (2013)
  arrange(frac) %>%  # order them
  pull(x) -> myOrder  # save vector to order by


df$x <- factor(df$x, levels = myOrder)  # apply ordering

ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(x, y, fill = f),
                      position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE), stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```

[image]